# How to keep navigation tab remain unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When I click a button on the sidebar, and if the current tab is the second tab the navigation tab is going to display the first tab as the second tab lost the focus. How can I keep the second tab in display while clicking a button on the sidebar?

the code is in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/98okrj0f/9/

The AngularJs scripts works at my local. Can anyone also tell me how to make it work in jsfiddle?

HTML Code here

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav</title>
    <link href="nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!--            -->
<body ng-app="App" >
  <nav>
    <ul> <span>My App</span>
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="#">Version</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#">V2</a>
                    <ul ng-controller="V2Ctrl">
                        <li ng-repeat = "v2 in V2s"><a href="#">{{v2}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#">V3</a>
                    <ul ng-controller="V3Ctrl">
                        <li ng-repeat = "v3 in V3s"><a href="#">{{v3}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
      <aside class="side" align="left">
         <table onclick="reply_click(event)" ng-app="App" ng-controller="TableCtrl" >
               <tr ng-repeat = "table in tables">
                 <td><button id = "{{table}}" width = "70">{{table}}</button></td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </aside>
  <article class="tabs">


      <section id="erd">
        <h2><a href="#erd">ERD</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab ERD.</p>
      </section>

      <section id="col">
        <h2><a href="#col">Columns</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab Columns.</p>
      </section>

      <section id="home">
        <h2><a href="#home">Home</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab Home. lfkdgl;k  lkfd;lkg ';lkfg ;lkg 'df;lk ;lk ';lk ';fdlkg ';fdlkg';dflk;ldfkg';lkdlfkdfkglkdf lkjhlsdjhfljdfhlkjdh jh jhkjdhfkjsdhf skjdhf lk h dsfjlkjsdlkfj;dslkfj  dskfj;kj sdfkj fkdj;lfkjsd;lkfj   sdkfj ;slkj sdfj;lskjf   skdj flksjdf ; sdfkj ;sdlkfj dskfj sdkjfhueuu suehu heu he u heu heh ueh ufhu fhe uueh ush uhsudh ue huhuhufheuheu u heiu h euh eh ue </p>
      </section>

  </article>


  <footer align="bottom">
    <span>"Copyright&copy; 2016 </span></span>
  </footer>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('App', []);
    app.controller('TableCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tables = ['category','supplier','customer','dept','empl','orders'];
    });
    app.controller('V2Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.V2s = ['2.10','2.11','2.12','2.13','2.14','2.15','2.16','2.17','2.18','2.19','2.20','2.21','2.22','2.23','2.24','2.25','2.26','2.27','2.28'];
    });  
    app.controller('V3Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.V3s = ['  ','   SP1','   SP2','   SP3','   SP4','   SP5','   SP6','   SP7','   SP8','   SP9','   SP10'];
    });  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code here.

```
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Helvetica Nueue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
}
na ul span {
    width: 300px
    margin-top: 250%;;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    /*padding: 0.5em 2em;*/
    padding: 0.2em 3em;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav li > ul{
    display : none;
    margin-top:1px;
    background-color: #bbb;

}

nav li > ul li{
    display: block;
}

nav  li > ul li a {
    color: #111;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.2em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
nav li:hover > ul{
    position:absolute;
    display : block;
}
nav li > ul > li ul  {
    display: none;
    background-color: #888;
}
nav li > ul > li:hover > ul  {
    position:absolute;
    display : block;
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-3em;
}

nav ul > li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_18dp.png) right center no-repeat;
    z-index: 5; 
    overflow: visible;
}

nav ul > li.sub li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_18dp.png) right center no-repeat;
    z-index: 5; 
    overflow: visible;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
aside {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 550px;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue
}

article {
/*  position: relative; */
}

article.tabs
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 2em; 
  margin-left:80px;
    background-color: green;

}
article.tabs section
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 0;
}
article.tabs section:first-child
{
    z-index: 1;
}
article.tabs section h2
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    height: 1.5em;
    top: -1.5em;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
    left: 132px;
}
/*
article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
    left: 254px;
}*/

article.tabs section h2 a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0 none;
}
article.tabs section:target,
article.tabs section:target h2
{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
article.tabs section,
article.tabs section h2
{
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
footer 
{
    color: #999;
  text-align:center
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

the update jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/98okrj0f/13/

Comment: At the left side of JSFiddle you can add external resources. This way you can add js files or jquery.

Comment: I tried to add url with http reference then it asked for https so I hit cancel. Somehow angular-min.js was added. then I hit update and then run. it still won't work. further idea?

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js

Comment: thanks for the url which I added. I remove my js code from within html <script> tag and put it in the javascript window. still not working. the link is https://jsfiddle.net/98okrj0f/17/ now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/98okrj0f/18/ Now it works. In the fiddle you posted there was no external resource. At the left of everything find external resources and see it's now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered you're question I will answer this question like I did the previous ones.

The problem was that you weren't closing you `<a>` tags with `</a>`. So the html added extra `<a>` tags with made the left bar also use a href which is used for your tabs. This way it overrided the open tab.

See the new JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98okrj0f/19/

Here's the code that was making the error's:

```
<li ng-repeat = "v2 in V2s"><a href="#">{{v2}}</a></li>
<li ng-repeat = "v3 in V3s"><a href="#">{{v3}}</a></li>
```